# Shimano 105 5800 front derailleur installation

Tags: shimano, gears, derailleur-front

I am currently installing a front derailleur as part of a new bike build.

It attaches to the frame via a braze on mount. I can't get it to shift onto the big ring. It shifts onto the big ring only when I'm on the smallest cog in the rear cassette.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Adjust the High-limit-screw on the front derailleur!

Comment: Have you used a double FD mech on a triple front chainring?

Comment: @Criggie Nope..

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that the cogs and chainset are too far out of line. You might need a different bottom bracket. I had similar problems converting a ladies Raleigh Richmond to 21 speed. A new bb solved it